# Angular translate not working between 2 controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-translate

I would like to use i18n and i10n in my Angular app.

I read that Angular-translate can help with this, however, it doesn't work for me.

In my index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="eApp">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../common/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../common/css/style.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
     <div id="container" ng-view></div>
    <!--- Libs Js files  --->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendor/angularjs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendor/angularjs/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In my eApp.js:

```
var eApp = angular.module('elbitApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'config', 'pascalprecht.translate']);

// configure our routes
eApp.config(["$routeProvider",
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/c', {
        templateUrl: 'c/partials/c.html',
        controller: 'CController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/de', {
        templateUrl: 'd/partials/dE.html',
        controller: 'DEController',
        resolve: {
            data: function (DDataService) {
                return DDataService.loadData().then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        }
    })

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/di', {
        templateUrl: 'd/partials/di.html',
        controller: 'DIController',
        resolve: {
            data: function (DDataService) {
                return DDataService.loadData().then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        }
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/di'
    });
}]).config(["$httpProvider",
function ($httpProvider) {
    // Configure the $httpProvider to parse date with date transformer
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.push(function (responseData) {
        convertDateStringsToDates(responseData);
        return responseData;
        }); 
}]).config(["$translateProvider",
    function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        "TITLE": 'Hello',
        "FOO": 'This is a paragraph.',
        "BUTTON_LANG_EN": 'english',
        "BUTTON_LANG_DE": 'german'
    });
      $translateProvider.translations('de', {
        "TITLE": 'Hallo',
        "FOO": 'Dies ist ein Paragraph.',
        "BUTTON_LANG_EN": 'englisch',
        "BUTTON_LANG_DE": 'deutsch'
      });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);


// main controller that catches resolving issues of the other controllers
eApp.controller('AppCtrl', function ($rootScope) {
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
    alert("Cant resolve the request of the controller "); //TODO: add URL + additional data.
})
});
```

In this file I defined my app and added the `$translateProvider` and two dictionaries.

Afterwards I got to my `deController.js`:

```
eApp.controller('DispatcherEventsController', ['$scope', '$route', '$translate', 
                    function($scope, $route, $translate){

    var data = $route.current.locals.data;



    $scope.title = $translate.instant("FOO");


    $scope.switchLanguage = function(languageKey){
        $translate.use(languageKey);
    };
}]);
```

In `de.html` I added a `h1` tag with `FOO` and in a click I would like to change to German:

```
<h1>{{title |translate}}</h1>
<h1 translate="{{title}}"></h1>
<button type="button" id="searchButton" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="switchLanguage('de')">German</button>
```

I don't get any problem, but nothing happens. I expected that the English title will be converted to German title.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: I got an error: TypeError: Object function has no method 'uses'. The app is crushed

Answer (score 3):

It works well for me. Here is a [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6GA27/1/).

In this case, you want to bind $scope.title with translation key "FOO".

You should change the value of $scope.title dynamically in the *switchLanguage* function. Then view will be updated accordingly.

```
//default value
$scope.title = $translate.instant("HEADLINE");

$scope.switchLanguage = function(key){
    $translate.use(key);
    $scope.title = $translate.instant("HEADLINE");
}
```

In my opinion, maybe use translation key is a better way than scope data binding. You don't have to maitain the value of key manually.

```
<h1>{{'FOO' | translate}}</h1>
```

According to the error msg you provided, maybe you could check if there is any typo syntax in your controller.

**Should be**

```
$translate.use(languageKey)
```

**Not**

```
$translate.uses(languageKey)
```

Comment: After changing `$translate.uses(languageKey)` to `$translate.use(languageKey)`, i still needed to change  `<h1>{{'FOO' | translate}}</h1>` to `<h1 translate="FOO"></h1>`.

Comment: Can you explain more detail about your problem. Actually <h1>{{'FOO' | translate}}</h1> is equivalant to <h1 translate="{{'FOO'}}"></h1>

Comment: Apparently not. The difference between my working code and the opposite is only this... I can't find nothing else.

Comment: So the jsfiddle demo of this answer is not what you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you also do interpolations? _<span translate="5 {{NEW_MESSAGES}}"></span>_?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having same problem - the filter doesn't refresh, but the directive does.. very strange

Comment: @spock Same problem here, have find the solution. directive works but not filter.

Comment: @expore> I found the problem,it is because of a race condition. When you switch language, the new language file will be downloaded. This happens async. Sometimes the bindings try to resolve before the language file has been downloaded. My problem was that I used one-time bindings, and I had to remove them again.

Answer (score 1):

Though not directly related to your question - you must remember to set the preferred language in the translations.js file, or whatever its name is that you define your key-value translations. Otherwise it will just default to whatever the key is.

```
... 
GREETING: 'Hello World!',
...
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

Without this line, when doing this:

```
<h2>{{'GREETING'|translate}}</h2>
```

Would appear as just **GREETING** instead of the 'Hello World.'